# AJAX Control Toolkit 16.1 Не правильное отображение TabContainer с сервера.

Tags: ajax, asp.net, iis-7

При создании сайта на .Net FrameWork 4.0 (VS 2015), при локальной проверки веб-сайта (на IIS-express) контрол TabContainer отображается нормально. Но после загрузки созданного сайта на сервер (на сервере IIS 7), происходит искажение внешнего вида контрола, функционал контрола (переключение вкладок) сохранятся.
Браузер IE 11.
[image: TabContainer текст смещен относительно кнопок]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX Control Toolkit очень активно проверяет поддерживаемые браузером фичи, через [`HttpBrowserCapabilities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities(v=vs.110).aspx), и, в зависимости от поддержки фич, рендерит разный HTML/JS.

`HttpBrowserCapabilities` заполняются на основе UserAgent браузера. А в IE 11 он резко поменялся. Вот как он выглядел в IE9, IE10 и IE11:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Из-за такого финта ASP.NET версии <= 4.0 считает IE11 каким-то древним мозиллой, без JS, без ничего - и AJAX Control Toolkit рендерит под него дикий трешевый HTML.

Вам придется или обновиться до .NET 4.5, или поставить на сервер [патчи для .NET 4.0, добавляющие распознование IE11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/) - они должны были дойти до сервера через Windows Update, но, судя по всему, на вашем сервере он отключен.

Локально у вас скорее всего работает из-за установленного .NET 4.5, или из-за вовремя установленных апдейтов.

---

UP (из комментариев)

Кроме того, в случае Intranet (не Internet) приложений IE по умолчанию работает в режиме максимальной совместимости, скорее всего в режиме IE7.

Это можно пробить, явно указав заголовок `X-UA-Compatible`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8, IE=9, IE=10, IE=11" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Указания `IE=Edge` может быть недостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, обновили на сервере .NET до 4.5.2, но проблему это не решило.
При теперь UserAgent выдает:
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)`
Но нашлось временное решение, определить режим документа как IE10 как [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @lord-lelik это intranet-приложение? Если да - то не повезло, IE по умолчанию в intranet (локальной сети) работает в compatibility mode. Можно отключить или на стороне IE (Tools / Compatibility Options) или оверрайдом на странице - но тогда лучше ставить оверрайд `"X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11"` или `"IE=11,IE=10,IE=9"` - он заставит IE11 работать как IE11, а не как IE7). Допишу в ответ.