# Браузер explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, настройка

Как поставить режим документов на Edge по умолчанию на explorer 11-e?

Answer (score 2):

Режим "edge" — это и есть режим по умолчанию для всех современных документов HTML. Никаких мета-заголовков никуда добавлять не надо, ничего настраивать не надо. Если документ имеет признаки нормального документа HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`, в частности), то всё будет нормально работать.

Если же документ не имеет признаков современного HTML-документа (имеет устаревший или вовсе отсутствующий DOCTYPE, например), то никакими настройками браузер не заставить отображать его как современный документ. С точки зрения браузера это может поломать сайт, поэтому он так делать не будет. Исправляйте сам документ.

Если же вы хотите проверить сайт на совместимость с новой версией, при этом сайт работает в режиме совместимости, то вы можете насильно переключить режим на панели разработчика.

Заголовок с режимом edge (`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`) может понадобиться в исключительно редком случае, когда вы управляете очень популярным сайтом, Microsoft включила ваш сайт в список неправильно работающих в новой версии браузера, вы проигнорировали это, исправили через год, и теперь хотите быть исключённым из списка глючных популярных сайтов.

Ещё в браузере есть настройка для отображения интранетных сайтов в режиме совместимости. Ей надо пользоваться с осторожностью, потому что сам сайт перекрыть эту настройку не сможет.

Comment: Настройка режима совместимости для интранет-сайтов включена по умолчанию, но сайт может её перекрыть, причем именно заголовком X-UA-Compatible, но не просто edge, а с перечисением конкретных версий - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509148/177221